# How to AnimatedCrossFade multiple widget with the pageView in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, widget

I have a column wherein the bottom half I have the `ListView` and on the upper half have the `Widget` that I want to crossfade between.

the `pageVirew` and the upper widget is an independent widget in a column.

there can be multiple pages in the `pageView` and there is a `Widget` in the upper half corresponding to each page in `PageView`.

A page is changed in the `PageView` how to crossfade the corresponding widget in the upper half part?

It looks something like this:-
[image]

Here as the yellow page is changed the corresponding widget i.e `Widget1` is charged to `Widget2`.
Here there any be any number of pages.

so far, I am thinking to place all the widgets in the stack with opacity 0 and slowly change the opacity to 1 when the page is changed. But this seems inefficient, it there any alternate approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a widget called **AnimatedSwitcher** to do the trick.
You can find it in details on YouTube in the *Flutter Widget of the Week* series [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W7POjFb88g)